# $\omega$-limits and $\alpha$-limits for $\theta'=1$ and $r'=r(r-2)(r-3)$, $r\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the differential equations $\theta'=1$ and $r'=r(r-2)(r-3)$, $r\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$.

I want to find the $\omega$-limits and the $\alpha$-limits. After a few simple considerations, I find that the orbits can be schematically drawn as below:

[image]
And for instance the $\omega$-limits seem to be
 $$\omega(r,\theta)=S^1_2 \,\,\text{ for } 0<r\le 2$$
 $$\omega(r,\theta)=S^1_2 \,\,\text{ for } 2<r< 3$$
 $$\omega(r,\theta)=S^1_3 \,\,\text{ for } r=3 $$
 $$\omega(r,\theta)=\emptyset \,\,\text{ for } r>3 $$

But how can I prove this *rigorously*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** the equations of this system are uncoupled and that makes them easy to analyze. If you can prove that solutions of $\dot{r} = r(r-2)(r-3)$ behave in a particular way (monotonous or constant, depending on initial condition $r_0$), then your qualitative analysis is rigorous enough.

Comment: So are you saying that if I prove that $r'>0$ in the inner ball, then it is proved that $\omega(r,\theta)=S^1_2$? That certainly sounds correct, but I want to see why this constitutes a proof, using the definition of $\omega$-limit directly.

Comment: I assumed that you should do the last step yourself :) You know the definition of $\omega$-limit point. Now you have to prove, for example, that any point $(2, \hat{\phi})$ is an $\omega$-limit point for trajectories from $0 < \vert r \vert < 3$. You  have to construct an increasing sequence $t_n$ such that trajectory comes closer and closer to $(2, \hat{\phi})$. You can easily construct that sequence using known behaviour of $r(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ and that $\phi$ is angle variable.